# Math opposite sign function?

Tags: math, function

Does such function exist? I created my own but would like to use an official one:

```
private function opposite(number:Number):Number
{
    if (number < 0)
    {
        number = Math.abs(number);
    }
    else
    {
        number = -(number);
    }
    return number;
}
```

So, -5 becomes 5 and 3 becomes -3.

Edit:
Forgive me for being stupid. I'm human. :)

Comment: Guys, seriously, why the downvotes?  We're supposed to be here to help each other.  This is a serious question, there's no need to be dicks about it.

Comment: @gnovice was thinking the same thing at first glance.

Comment: How about *-1? That isn't "official" but its just a multiplication...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

yes it does...

```
return num*-1;
```

or simply

```
return -num;
```

Comment: The only correct answer, as far as I'm concerned. No more answers needed.

Comment: As long as this is a compiled language where the compiler can optimize that multiplication away.

Comment: Not sure why you got so many upvotes with this. Hello!?!? If only for clarity for the next programmer to see it, "return -num;"

Comment: @Emtucifor, multiplication is still performed either way. This answer is not wrong.

Comment: @John T, not true if the number is stored in two's compliment. The value of -num can be computed by flipping all the bits and adding one (~num + 1) which is significantly faster than multiplication.

Comment: @Kevin, yes but when using a compiled language, both will be compiled to a single NEGL instruction performed on the register so it does not matter. When compiled there is no difference as the multiplication is removed. My answer is not necessarily wrong, just 2 characters longer than needed. Downvotes are for incorrect answers or bad information, this is neither.

Comment: I call this bad information because "compiler-correctness" is not the only criterion for good code. I'll remove my downvote, but in my shop I would call this answer from a developer wrong and would make him change it.

Answer (score 26):

How about:

```
return -(number)
```

as `-(-5) == 5`.

Answer (score 21):

Simply putting a negative sign in front of the variable or number will do the trick, even if it's already negative:

```
-(-5) => 5
$foo = 3; -$foo => -3
```

Answer (score 4):

This a trick question?  why a function?  just do number * -1, multiply with -1 that is.

Answer (score 2):

try something like number = number * (-1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
number *= -1;
```

3 becomes -3 and -5 becomes 5 :)